# How to get (x,y) coordinates given MinGX, MinGY, MaxGX, MaxGY?

Tags: coordinates

I have a set of data that stores the MinGX, MinGY, MaxGX, MaxGY values of each location. I need to find the (x,y) coordinates of these locations. Is there any way to do this without using/downloading any software? Also, is it possible to plot the map given these 4 values by using any software?

Comment: What does "the coordinate" mean? MinGX, MinGY, MaxGX and MaxGY together represent a rectangle. Do you want to calculate the centroid coordinate (the center of the rectangle)?

Comment: I need to find the (x,y) coordinates of these points. My goal eventually is to calculate the distances between these points

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Policy here is to have one question per question.  All questions should be tightly focused, which includes specifying the GIS software in use. If you just want to parse data without GIS software, then this really isn't a GIS question.  Please be sure to edit the question in response to requests for clarification, as it isn't fair to those how would answer to need to read the comments for critical information.

Comment: P1 is at (mingx, mingy), P2 at (mingx, maxgy), P3 at (maxgx, maxgy) and P4 at (maxgx, mingy). Do you mean that?

Comment: No, P1 is at (MinGX, MinGY, MaxGX and MaxGY)

Comment: unless the value of mingy, maxgy are identical, p1 is not a point. it looks to me as though possibly your array is a bounding box. This question has some serious flaws. in order to make it answerable, you will need to either direct it toward a specific software. or remove the software aspect and concentrate on the resolution of what a coordinate is.

Answer (score 1):

The points look like this, when drawn in a cartesian coordinate system:
[image: point layout]